# SVN - Erase and overwrite remote repository

Tags: svn

## Here is the problem:

- I have an svn remote host which is connected to my local svn repository.
- The remote host is then overwritten by another svn repository.
- When I execute `svn update` in my local repository, it says the `UUID` does not agree (Since the host and local are now 2 different repositories).
- **How do I overwrite the remote host `URL` with my local svn repository again?**

PS. the local repository still has the old `.svn` directory, where as the remote host's `.svn` is overwritten by another repository.

Comment: Why don't you checkout again?

Comment: That will overwrite my local repo

Comment: You wrote: "remote host is then overwritten". Why? What happened? I think I misunderstood you.

Comment: A different repository used `svn import $REMOTE-HOST` and overwrote the content of the remote host.